# What's causing segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Please help me with this SIGSEGV error from calling the function below in my program:

```
int* calculateFitness(int** population, int** townDistancesMatrix, int chromoSize){
    int sum = 0;
    static int* Fitnesses;
    Fitnesses = malloc(sizeof(int)*chromoSize); 
    for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++){
        int indexOne = 0;
        int indexTwo = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<chromoSize-1; j++){
            indexOne = population[i][j];
            indexTwo = population[i][j+1];
            //printf("\n%d %d",indexOne-1,indexTwo-1);
            sum += townDistancesMatrix[indexOne-1][indexTwo-1];
        }
        indexOne = population[i][0];
        sum += townDistancesMatrix[indexTwo-1][indexOne-1];
        Fitnesses[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    return Fitnesses;
}
```

Program runs without problem for smaller inputs(like 5 towns) so I first doubted that it was a stackoverflow, because program always runs for sometime (until similar value of i for all runs (`i=20`)) and then stops running and gives this error(in GDB):

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000008000b9b in calculateFitness (population=0x7ffffffedcd0, townDistancesMatrix=0x8403470, chromoSize=48) at Untitled1.c:97
>   97                              sum += townDistancesMatrix[indexOne-1][indexTwo-1];

However, I have no recursive function calls in `calculateFitness` so I thought maybe it was caused by large local variables in my function, but the local variables are few and small and my arrays are also created dynamically and don't go on stack(Maybe the problem is with my nested loop?).

I also ran valgrind (although I'm not yet very familiar with its reports and I just use it to get some hints) and here's the report:

```
==198== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
==198== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==198==    at 0x108B41: calculateFitness (Untitled1.c:92)
==198==    by 0x108866: main (Untitled1.c:29)
==198==
==198== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==198==    at 0x108B6E: calculateFitness (Untitled1.c:93)
==198==    by 0x108866: main (Untitled1.c:29)
==198==
==198== Invalid read of size 4
==198==    at 0x108B9B: calculateFitness (Untitled1.c:97)
==198==    by 0x108866: main (Untitled1.c:29)
==198==  Address 0x522d43c is 4 bytes before a block of size 192 alloc'd
==198==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck- 
amd64-linux.so)
==198==    by 0x108A56: readDistances (Untitled1.c:74)
==198==    by 0x1087EB: main (Untitled1.c:19)
==198==
==198== Invalid read of size 8
==198==    at 0x108B87: calculateFitness (Untitled1.c:97)
==198==    by 0x108866: main (Untitled1.c:29)
==198==  Address 0x522d278 is 8 bytes before a block of size 384 alloc'd
==198==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck- 
amd64-linux.so)
==198==    by 0x108A20: readDistances (Untitled1.c:71)
==198==    by 0x1087EB: main (Untitled1.c:19)
==198==
==198==
==198== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==198==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFC000018
==198==    at 0x108B9B: calculateFitness (Untitled1.c:97)
==198==    by 0x108866: main (Untitled1.c:29)
==198==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==198==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==198==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==198==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==198==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

//...

==198== LEAK SUMMARY:
==198==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==198==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==198==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==198==    still reachable: 13,632 bytes in 70 blocks
==198==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I searched parts of this error like "still reachable" and it seems not to be something I need to pay attention to, but I'm not sure about the meaning of first parts even after searching them. What am I doing wrong? If it's really a stackoverflow, what are other causes of a stackoverflow other than recursions?

Comment: After the first time you call the function you will have *memory leaks* (unless you free the pointer allocated for `Fitnesses` somewhere else). Why is the variable `Fitnesses` even `static`? What's the reason for it?

Comment: As for your problem, which is the lines `155` and `161` in the code you show? When the crash happens, have you examined the values of all involved variables to see that they are valid? And where's the [mcve] we need to help you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll give the link to the code in a moment. I used static because I wanted to access it after function call terminated. Yes I free it in main afterwards.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Here's the link to the code with same line numbers (I do not delete a few test lines(printfs) so that line numbers remain unchanged): https://paste2.org/AP8NaYMe

Comment: Regarding the `static` variable, that's not needed when you return a pointer to heap-allocated memory. You return the *value* of the variable, not a pointer to the variable itself.

Comment: And we don't need the whole program, instead (as mentioned) create a [mcve] to show us. It could also help you understand what the problem is yourself. And a big hint is in the output of Valgrind: "Use of uninitialised value". It seems you're using uninitialized variables, which means their values will be indeterminate (and seemingly random). Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and possible crashes like yours.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, I will fix that in a moment, but do I have to type line numbers to conform with the question?! (this is why I pasted the whole code there)

Comment: No, just add comments on the lines mentioned to mark them out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude New link, I hope it's not as unreadable as the previous one: https://paste2.org/3hnmP7LP Thanks. (Also an example input for reproducing the error is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4l3t1lr0l12enll/input_att48.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @M-J increase _POPSIZE_ if you want to use the values from `input_att48.txt`,  look at my answer for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(){
  int* population[POPSIZE];
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++){
    int indexOne = 0;
    int indexTwo = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<chromoSize-1; j++){
        indexOne = population[i][j];
        indexTwo = population[i][j+1];
```

You access out of *population* (signaled by *valgrind*), the value 48 you give to `chromo_size` (initializing *chromoSize* above) from your input file is too large with *POPSIZE* equals to 20

After *indexOne* and *indexTwo* have random value so the accesses of *townDistancesMatrix* produces the seg fault signaled by valgrind

In *main* after the `scanf("%d",&chromo_size);` check the value is <= *POPSIZE* to avoid that problem, and increase *POPSIZE* to be able to run with your input file

---

Note also the `free(population)` is illegal because *population* is a local variable, it is not allocated in the heap

Comment: It's fixed now and is working! But I don't know why still although POPSIZE 50 works fine, POPSIZE 1000 gives a `double free or corruption (!prev) Aborted (core dumped)`. I'm new to this error and I have to search it but do you have any guesses, please? Thanks for your help a lot.

Comment: @M-J You have the core dump, so just use a debugger giving it the exe and the core and it will show where it occurs, or I suppose if you run under valgrind it will signal also where your problems are when POPSIZE if 1000. You already have an invalid free I signaled to you, did you removed it ?